# Nuxt 3 extend NuxtApp type with custom plugins

Tags: typescript, plugins, nuxt.js

When i provide plugin to nuxtApp it knows its type

[image]

but when i try to use it on the page it show only type "any"
[image]

Can i add types to extend NuxtApp type mannualy? or what can i do for it to know the right type of plugin?

i think about something like this

```
import type { order } from '~/plugins/order'

interface PluginsInjections {
  $order: ReturnType<order>
}

declare global {
  interface NuxtApp extends PluginsInjections {}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out

I looked up how it's done in i18n plugin
[image: i18n plugin]

and did the same for myself in types/index.d.ts

```
import type { order } from '~/plugins/order'

interface PluginsInjections {
  $order: ReturnType<typeof order>
}

declare module '#app' {
  interface NuxtApp extends PluginsInjections {}
}

declare module 'nuxt/dist/app/nuxt' {
  interface NuxtApp extends PluginsInjections {}
}

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties extends PluginsInjections {}
}
```

now it knows that the plugin exists, and helping with auto complete
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to manually add types for properties and functions injected by plugins since it's supposed to work automatically as explained in the docs: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#typing-plugins Instead, you should investigate why the automatic detection is not working as expected.

More advanced usecases can require you to manually define the types of injected properties. In that case you can follow this example:

```js
// Your plugin
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  return {
    provide: {
      hello: (msg: string) => `Hello ${msg}!`
    }
  }
})

// index.d.ts
declare module '#app' {
  interface NuxtApp {
    $hello (msg: string): string
  }
}

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $hello (msg: string): string
  }
}

export { }
```

from: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#advanced

But do remember that doing this masks the consequences of another issue in your code base instead of solving the root cause.

Comment: Updated to better reflect the point I was trying to make. Manually adding the types doesn't fix the fact that the automatic detection doesn't work.